# DLL that uses QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

I want to create DLL which opens a dialog do some processing with QGIS and returns some data. I have searched many places but have not found the help I needed.

I just want to read shapefiles and then show shape data. So I wanted to know how to make a DLL that uses QGIS processes? I have searched on internet but did not find any QGIS DLL or library that we can use to build DLL. So I want to know is there any way to create a DLL that uses QGIS and then we can use DLL in any other project?

Comment: Hi, the short answer is yes. But to provide a good answer we will need some more information about what your problems are.

Comment: sir i just want to read shape files and show shape data. and i want to make this DLL and then this DLL can be used in any project

Comment: QGIS is built around several DLL's itself, you can easily build your own DLL that are linked against the QGIS DLL's. How to do this is a question related to software engineering in general and should be asked on stackoverflow (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127755/linking-dll-to-dll) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392174/cmake-link-against-dll-lib))

Comment: ok i got it. sir one last thing whats the qgis DLL for reading shape file?

Comment: i hve edited why its still onhold? I got stuck in this issue and really need some help

Answer (score 1):

PyQGIS is the standard way to work with/automate QGIS processes and get it to do what you want it to do.  Just call a PyQGIS script from your project.

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

Comment: sir its python script? is there any way for c++ or c# ?